# cin to vector input loops indefinitely. Why?

Tags: c++, vector, while-loop, cin

Okay, so I browsed around and found the following implementation on hackerrank for [bubble sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cShPI.png).

Now, this uses the following while loop for the input:

```
while (cin >> t)
```

It executes on the hackerrank site, but not in my IDE (CLion, as you can see), i.e. the program keeps on accepting input indefinitely. I've also found that many posts on the site also use or suggest similar code when it comes to taking input into vectors. I'm currently using the other methods suggested in the stackoverflow posts, some working others not so much. My question is

- why is the program accepting input indefinitely?
- are there any conditions/like flags and such that this violates?
- did this get removed in C++14 or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when you run an executable file, its standard input is bound to some interactive medium (a terminal or console). Such a medium does not normally have and end, unless you send an end-of-file explicitly (such as using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on Linux). So the loop will never terminate, since reading can always just block and wait for more input.

This is different if you redirect the executable's standard output to read from a file instead. In a typical shell, this is what you'd achieve using `<`:

```
myprog < file.txt
```

This way, the program's standard input will be a file descriptor for the file, and reading from it will signal an EOF normally when you read to the file's end.

Comment: Thanks angew!! That made sense.

Answer (score 0):

In C language structure I use

```
while(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)==2) 
or
while(scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)!=EOF)
```

to get input continuously

I tried `int x=scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)` to see whats going on
and it gives me x=2 and thats why the loop running continuously (cause 2==2)

for C++ input stream will give you a boolean value(if I'm not wrong)
you can check `bool x=cin>>var;`  to see the value.
And for correct input it will always give 1.
so `while(cin>>something)` actually means `while(1)`
and thats why the loop taking input continuously.
Its not a good answer but it makes sense I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(std::cin >> somevar &&
      somevar != "\n")
{ }
```

I would recommend this solution if you know the terminating sequence.

Comment: Naw. Tried that didn't work. Well I think once we take the required number of inputs, we can just add a delimiting character at the end programmatically i.e. like a null character '\0' to end. Of course that wouldn't look so clean. I wanted it to work because that code looked super clean to me ;)